# SQL Query Slow When Ordering by a PK Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why does this query take a long time (30+ seconds) to run?

A:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Workflow] ORDER BY ID DESC
```

But this query is fast (0 seconds):

B:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Workflow] ORDER BY ReadTime DESC
```

And this is fast (0 seconds), too:

C:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Workflow] WHERE SubId = '120611250634'
```

I get why B and C are fast:

B:
[image]

C:
[image]

But I don’t get why A takes so long when we have this:

[image]

Edit: The estimated execution plan using ID:

[image]

Edit: The estimated execution plan using ReadTime:

[image]

Comment: What does the execution plan for query (A) say?

Comment: You may try to recreate the issue on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) as well.

Comment: @marc_s I added the execution plan to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your primary key is for *both* ID (ASC) and ReadTime (ASC). The order is not important when you're only having a single column index, but it does matter when you have more columns in the index (a composite key).

Composite clustered keys are not really made for ordering. I'd expect that using

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Workflow] ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Will be rather fast, and the best would be

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Workflow] ORDER BY ID, ReadTime
```

Reversing the order is a tricky operation on a composite key.

So in effect, when you order by `ReadTime`, you have an index ready for that, and that index also knows the exact key of the row involved (both its `Id` and `ReadTime` - another good reason to keep the clustered index very narrow). It can look up all the columns rather easily. However, when you order by `Id`, you don't have an exact fit of an index. The server doesn't trivially know how many rows there are for a given `Id`, which means the `top` gets a bit trickier than you'd guess. In effect, your clustered index turns into a waste of space and performance (as far as those sample queries are concerned).

Seeing just the tiny part of your database, I'd say having a clustered index on Id and ReadTime is a bad idea. Why do you do that?

Comment: Having a clustered index on Id and ReadTime is indeed a bad idea. It was a mistake in design that was done before I was even employed here. So the right thing to do would be to change the PK to just Id, or to add an index for ID.

Comment: Yep. And if your ID is `identity`, it's a pretty good clustered key for a table. While you don't usually do range searches on the ID (range searches are very fast on clustered keys), they do make for tiny "reference" keys - all your indexes have the clustered key as a reference to the "physical" location of the data. Adding a non-clustered key for the Id is also an option, but it's only worth exploring if you have another great candidate for a clustered key - if not, just make Id the PK and clustered key and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `ID` isn't a PK by itself, but along with `ReadTime` (based on your 3rd picture).

Therefore the index is built on the `(ID,ReadTime)` pair, and this index isn't used by your query.

Try adding an index on `ID` only.